# How to open the gallery using the file path in android

Tags: android, file

I have designed two buttons.One button for selecting the file and another button for to open the selected file.I have selected the file correctly and the file path also retrieved.But i cant open the particular file directly by the file path.Any one I have tried something like this

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                        + selectedFilePath);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` [does not accept a `Uri` as input](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT).

Second, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has nothing to do with opening a file. Presumably, you should be using `ACTION_VIEW`.

Third, the value that you are passing to `Uri.parse()` is not a `String` form of a `Uri`.

Also, I would expect few Android devices to have an `ACTION_VIEW` activity for `text/csv` content.

Comment: can u explain with some example @Commonsware